# Google Now API - Possible Boarding/Event Pass & Gmail integration

Tags: api, google-now

Can we create a Gmail based Event /Boarding Pass Card? What's the format of this Card?

Do we have API to customize this? I only need to update data element. Once the user gets this in Gmail / it will scan this data & will get automatically load in Google Now API.
I am using Android 4.1.2 OS which has Google Search API which has Google Now Widget API with it.Is this do-able option & we have any Google Now API available to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **guess**

- Google Now appears to be an integral part of Glass.
- As the nomenclature is similar (cards)
- The general shape of the cards look Glass-like

I think it'll be highly probable that they're using google-glass APIs.

Someone ought to get wireshark on the case however.